# How can I do the equivalent of appending an array to a list in numba?

Tags: python, numba

I think my code isn't working because I have a list of arrays. Is there a different way I can structure the `final_list` list of arrays as a matrix so that it is accepted by `numba`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numba as nb
N_SPLITS = 1000

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def logi(x0, r):
  x = x0
  for n in range(30000):
     x = x * r * (1-x)
  final_list = [x]
  for n in range(N_SPLITS):
     final_list.append(final_list[-1] * r * ( 1 - final_list[-1]))
  return np.sort(final_list, axis=0)

r = np.arange(2.4, 4., .001)
for i in range(N_SPLITS):
   plt.plot(r, logi(0.5, r)[i], c='k', lw=0.1)
plt.savefig('bifig.pdf')




  File "logi.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.plot(r, logi(0.5, r)[i], c='k', lw=0.1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 330, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
numba.errors.TypingError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 235, in run
    stage()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 449, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 805, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 767, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
TypingError: Invalid usage of BoundFunction(list.append for list(float64)) with parameters (array(float64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized
File "logi.py", line 13
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(list.append for list(float64))
[2] During: typing of call at logi.py (13)

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Invalid usage of BoundFunction(list.append for list(float64)) with parameters (array(float64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized
File "logi.py", line 13
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(list.append for list(float64))
[2] During: typing of call at logi.py (13)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code that were causing issues for the numba jit-compiler:

- `np.sort` with arguments is not valid nor is using it on a 2D array
  (see:  [numpy supported
  features](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#other-methods))
- `x` changes from a float to an array. Numba requires type consistency throughout a function

Below is a numba function that compiles in `nopython` mode and produces the same results. Basically I pre-allocate storage arrays since the sizes are know in advance and then sort per-column. Unfortunately `numba` doesn't have a really good sort implementation, so you don't get a really large speed-up. There might be other performance tuning changes you can make. Also note that it doesn't make sense to call `logi` in each loop of the plotting section and then pull out a single value. Just calculate the array once and then pick out the values you need.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numba as nb
N_SPLITS = 1000

%matplotlib inline

def logi_orig(x0, r):
    x = x0
    for n in range(30000):
        x = x * r * (1-x)
    final_list = [x]
    for n in range(N_SPLITS):
        final_list.append(final_list[-1] * r * ( 1 - final_list[-1]))
    return np.sort(final_list, axis=0)

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def logi_nb(x0, r):
    x = np.full_like(r, x0)
    for n in range(30000):
        x = x * r * (1-x)
    final_list = np.empty((N_SPLITS + 1, r.shape[0]), dtype=np.float64)
    final_list[0,:] = x
    for n in range(1, N_SPLITS + 1):
        final_list[n, :] = final_list[n - 1] * r * ( 1 - final_list[n - 1])

    out = np.empty_like(final_list)
    for n in range(r.shape[0]):
        out[:,n] = np.sort(final_list[:,n])

    return out

def logi(x0, r):
    x = np.full_like(r, x0)
    for n in range(30000):
        x = x * r * (1-x)
    final_list = np.empty((N_SPLITS + 1, r.shape[0]), dtype=np.float64)
    final_list[0,:] = x
    for n in range(1, N_SPLITS + 1):
        final_list[n, :] = final_list[n - 1] * r * ( 1 - final_list[n - 1])

    return np.sort(final_list, axis=0)

r = np.arange(2.4, 4., .001)

y_orig = logi_orig(0.5, r)
y = logi(0.5, r)
y_nb = logi_nb(0.5, r)

print np.allclose(y, y_orig)
print np.allclose(y_nb, y_orig)

for i in range(N_SPLITS):
    plt.plot(r, y[i], c='k', lw=0.1)
```

And timings on OSX (2014 MBP) with Numba v0.34.0:

```
%timeit logi_orig(0.5, r)
%timeit logi(0.5, r)
%timeit logi_nb(0.5, r)

10 loops, best of 3: 171 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 77 ms per loop
```